# PowerMockito - How do I use whenNew() with a typed List?

Tags: java, generics, powermock

I want PowerMockito to return my empty array-list of `Foo`s when `new ArrayList<Foo>()` is called, but I am not sure how to construct the statement. Specifically, I want `new ArrayList<AnyOtherType>()` to create a new list as normal.

```
ArrayList<Foo> fooList = new ArrayList<Foo>();
PowerMockito.whenNew(ArrayList.class).withParameterTypes(Foo.class).thenReturn(fooList);
```

^ Here's basically what I have, but `.withParameterTypes(Foo.class)` does not allow me to follow with a `.thenReturn()`. My only option is `withArguments(firstArgument, additionalArguments)`.

Is this possible with PowerMock, and if so, how do I construct it?

EDIT:

Ok, the underlying problem is I need to get the result of the method I'm trying to test, but I had to mock the request, and the list is placed in the request at the end of the method I'm trying to test.

```
inspectionAction.viewInspectionDetailsAjax(mapping, form, request, response);
```

This method pulls a couple of parameters from the request, which is mocked (`Mockito.mock(HttpServletRequest.class);`). Usually in our app we place data on a session-level variable. But since this method is called several times at once and the results ajax'd into the page, each piece of data is stored in the request instead:

```
request.setAttribute("inspectionAjaxDetails", details);
```

So I need some way to get `details`, which is a typed ArrayList, when `request` is mocked.

Comment: Try `.withNoArguments` instead of `.withParameterTypes`.

Comment: How, then, do I specify just `ArrayList<Foo>` instead of all new ArrayLists?

Comment: This is another reason why it's generally not a good idea to try to mock collection classes.  It's better to create the collection you want returned by something, and coerce other methods to return that list.

Comment: This has more to do with generics and erasure than PowerMock. You cannot mock the List in such a way that you can capture the generic type parameter along with it. Additionally, as @DavidM.Karr points out, there's no really good reason to mock a `Collection` class. You may want to have it contain instances of mock objects but the `Collection` itself will be easier to work with if you leave it alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: You can't. As Matt Lachman pointed out in the comments, you can't capture the generics of a type, so you can't get `List<Foo>` without also getting `List<Bar>` and `List<AnyOtherType>`. Because collections are used so heavily, it is almost always a bad idea to try to capture them with PowerMock.

In my case, I needed to get a List that was given to a mocked `HttpServletRequest` as an attribute (mapped `<String, Object>`) in the method I was trying to test. I had to find a different solution. In my case, it was to create a non-anonymous implementation of `Answer` that I could retrieve values from after the method was run. My Mockito call looked like this:

```
RequestAnswer requestAnswer = new RequestAnswer();

Mockito.doAnswer(requestAnswer).when(request).setAttribute(Matchers.anyString(), Matchers.anyObject());

ArrayList<Foo> details = (ArrayList<Foo>) requestAnswer.getAttribute("foo");
```

My RequestAnswer class implements `Answer<Object>`, and its most important method looks like this:

```
@Override
public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
    Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
    String methodName = invocation.getMethod().getName();
    if ("setAttribute".equals(methodName)) {
        String key = (String) args[0];
        Object value = args[1];
        attributes.put(key, value);
    } else if ("getAttribute".equals(methodName)) {
        String key = (String) args[0];
        return attributes.get(key);
    } else if ("getParameter".equals(methodName)) {
        String key = (String) args[0];
        return parameters.get(key);
    }
    return null;
}
```

The rest was just a couple of Maps and getters and setters.