# How to expect a new arraylist object in powermock?

Tags: powermock, expectations

I have a code which has below two new List objects of different type:

```
List<TypeOne> typeOneList =  new ArrayList<TypeOne>();
List<TypeTwo> typeTwoList =  new ArrayList<TypeTwo>();
```

How can I use PowerMock.expectNew() to return two different ArrayList objects? Like..

```
PowerMock.expectNew(ArrayList.class).andReturn(typeOneList);
PowerMock.expectNew(ArrayList.class).andReturn(typeTwoList);
```

How we can differentiate in the above statement as for which statement the objects corresponds to?

thanks!

Comment: Short answer: it's not possible. For additional details please see this answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/19229553/4293320

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. You have to define in the below way in the order you want..

```
PowerMock.expectNew(ArrayList.class).andReturn(typeOneList); //first expect list object of TypeOne
PowerMock.expectNew(ArrayList.class).andReturn(typeTwoList); //then expect list object of TypeTwo
```

and powermock will return the objects in the order of expectations when the below code executes:

```
List<TypeOne> typeOneList =  new ArrayList<TypeOne>();
List<TypeTwo> typeTwoList =  new ArrayList<TypeTwo>();
```